# Get discord notifications based on message content

Tags: discord

I'm looking for a way to customise notifications based on discord message content (or get an alert some other way). The use case is my guild raid lead always posts raid signups in a particular format. I want notifications for these messages so I can sign up before the raid fills, but I don't want notifications for all the messages from people saying "+DD", "+heal" etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Are those raid signups posted in a separate channel to all of the other messages? Is it associated with a @mention?

Comment: This is a question about Discord more than it is about anything else. Better post it in Super User: https://superuser.com/